# Did Vladimir Horowitz ever record Rachmaninoff's Second Piano Concerto?

Tags: piano, recording

As Rachmaninoff and Horowitz knew each other personally I would have expected there to be at least one famous recording of the Second Piano Concerto by Horowitz, however I cannot find one.

So I am wondering whether such a recording exists (if so where can I listen to it?) and if not, was there a reason given by Horowitz for not recording this, given the Third Piano Concerto is widely regarded as more difficult than the Second.

Comment: it's a good question, since Horowitz's name is so closely connected with the 3rd piano concerto.  Certainly [discogs](https://www.discogs.com/artist/847818-Vladimir-Horowitz) doesn't have anything.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be that way, no.